# How to access mysql database with only user+pass?

Tags: mysql, database, redirect, cpanel

My website's database got infected & site url is changed. And it's redirecting to another website when visiting website url [like mydomain.com to blahblahblah.cc]

I have my website's mysql database username+pass [through config.php] & public_html access

But don't have access to cpanel/hosting.

So, can I access mysql database with only user+pass, without cpanel/hosting access?

or fix that anyhow?

Comment: The person who *does* have access to the hosting should be fixing this, because the issue goes far beyond just undoing the database damage.

Comment: Thanks...It's fixed now by correcting wp_options table but I would like to find a way to access database directly without cpanel login...

Comment: Again, undoing the database changes won't fix the security hole that allowed this. The attacker (and many other automated bots that look for vulnerable WordPress sites) will return and do it again. You need to fix the underlying problem, and to do that, you need full access to the code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind guidance. I'll try to follow this....

Comment: Hi again, Do you know How to find this security hole of redirection?